# Google Auto Complete setBounds not a function error

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-autocomplete

I am using googles address autocomplete and in the console it is throwing an error.

> caught TypeError: autocomplete.setBounds is not a function

the code is:

```
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
```

Is there a reason why setBounds would not work anymore? It used to function properly without erroring.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/89nqv5v5/

Comment: Whatever `autocomplete` is it's not declared in the code you've added to the question. How you've declared it, and what you've assigned to it, will determine what the problem is, but since we can't see that code, we can't help debug it.

Comment: Dang okay. There was too much code I tried to simplify it. Ill try to create a fiddle then so I dont flood the question with code

Comment: Maybe use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to create a [mcve]. We don't need to see _all_ the code necessarily, just the part where `autocomplete` has been declared, and any code that operates on it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/89nqv5v5/

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to work. Except the part where you are not checking if places are selected and you might get some console errors. But other than that, it seems to work.

Potential issues: I noticed you are only calling initialise function on body onLoad method. If you have something else in your body taking  long to load, your initialise might not be loaded before the first time you call `autocomplete.setBounds` (this might also happen if you have a script file imported in your html that is taking long to load).

So I would recommend you to call the function onLoad directly in the js file (so at the end of the js file just call `initialise()` and remove the `onLoad` part from your html).